# Could you explain this "chroot" /tmp directory creation?

Tags: linux, mount, chroot, tmp

In the following linked article they explain how to create a "chroot" /tmp directory. I'm a bit confused by what they did. Could someone explain what the following commands are doing?

**[Noexec and /tmp Troubleshooting](https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1987/Noexec+and+%7B47%7Dtmp+Troubleshooting#dv_40)**

```
1. # mkdir -p /root/chroot /root/tmp 
2. # mount --bind / /root/chroot 
3. # mount --bind /root/tmp /root/chroot/tmp
4. # chroot /root/chroot
```

In the first step, why did they create **/root/tmp** and not **/root/chroot/tmp**?

Does the first mount command affects the second one? On the second step they are binding the new directory **/root/chroot** to the root directory. Does that mean that on the third step **/root/tmp** actually points to **/root/chroot/root/tmp** ? Where does **/root/chroot/tmp** comes from? That's the part I'm getting confused.

What's the logic behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In step 2 you bind mounted `/` on `/root/chroot`.

If you create step 2.5 as `ls /root/chroot` you'll find all the directories of `/` listed; including the system's `/tmp` directory.

If you `touch /root/chroot/test` you'll see that `test` is also in the output of `ls /`. If you `rm /test` you'll notice that it's also gone from `/root/chroot/`. So `/` and `/root/chroot/` are exactly the same place.

If you want to look in slightly more detail, run `stat /` and then `stat /root/chroot` and you'll notice that both return the same `Inode`.  An `Inode` is a data structure that refers to a particular file/directory on the disk. As they both return the same `Inode` then both paths are pointing to exactly the same directory.

Step 3 therefore bind mounts the `/root/tmp` directory over the system `/tmp` directory within the already bind mounted `/root/chroot`.

When you `chroot` in step 4, you'll be in a chrooted `/` using the `/tmp` directory in `/root` instead of the system wide `/tmp`.  This way, the chroot isn't sharing a `/tmp` with every other user on the system.

Comment: Does the second step only affect /root/chroot or does it affect / too? Is it wrong to think that any path now starting by / will point to /root/chroot? Os it's the other way around, /root/chroot is the one pointing to / ? I think that's where I'm getting messed up!

Comment: I've tried to explain some more.  Keep at it...

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it now. I had the idea that there was some kind of "string replacing" taking place when resolving the path.

Answer (score 4):

```
mkdir -p /root/chroot /root/tmp
```

Create directories to be used for chroot'ed environment. `/root/chroot` will be the root directory of your chroot'ed environment. `/root/tmp` will act as a `/tmp` directory of your chroot'ed environment.

```
mount --bind / /root/chroot
```

This will make your `/` directory accessible via `/root/chroot`. Think about this as mirroring `/` directory on `/root/chroot` (even though it's not really a mirror, it's a pointer to `/`).

```
mount --bind /root/tmp /root/chroot/tmp
```

This will make your custom `/root/tmp` directory accessible via a `/tmp` directory of you chroot'ed environment. This way your chroot'ed environment will have it's `/tmp` directory separated from system's `/tmp`. If you skip this step then chroot'ed `/tmp` directory will point to your system's `/tmp` directory.

```
chroot /root/chroot
```

Here you enter your chroot'ed environment.

Now your questions:

1. Does the first mount command affect the second one?

   Yes. You need to bind mount the root of your chroot'ed environment (`/root/chroot`), before you can bind it's `/tmp` directory. `/root/chroot/tmp` won't exist before you bind `/` to `/root/chroot`.
2. On the second step they are binding the new directory `/root/chroot` to the root directory. Does that mean that on the third step `/root/tmp` actually points to `/root/chroot/root/tmp`?

   Yes. Everything on `/` will be accessible via `/root/chroot`.
3. Where does `/root/chroot/tmp` come from?

   `/root/chroot/tmp` comes into existence after you bind `/` to `/root/chroot` in step 2.